# routine for an sample to make an better routine for my example

Tags: php, sql

i want to ask you if someone have an idea how i can make it over an for or foreach Routine easier for me, because i dont want to copy paste all the stuff for all routines

```
if ( $_POST['vorgang'] == 'aendern' ) { 
    pd_aendern  ( $_POST['db_eintrag'] , $db_id ); 
}

<form action="#"  runat="server" method="POST"    enctype="multipart/form-data">

    echo '<input type="text" placeholder="'  . $vorname       . '"name="db_eintrag[pd_vorname]"><br>';
    echo '<input type="text" placeholder="'  . $nachname      . '"name="db_eintrag[pd_nachname]"><br>';
    echo '<input type="text" placeholder="'  . $geburtsjahr   . '"name="db_eintrag[pd_geburtsjahr]"><br>';
    ...
    ..
    .
</form>

function pd_aendern ( $db_eintrag , $db_id ) {
////////////////
//1st Routine.//             
////////////////
    if (!empty(isset($db_eintrag[pd_vorname] ))) {
        $sql = "UPDATE personaldaten SET pd_vorname='$db_eintrag[pd_vorname]' WHERE pd_id='$db_id'";
        $db_erg = mysql_query( $sql );
        if ( ! $db_erg ) { 
            die("Ungültige Abfrage: $sql <hr>" . mysql_error()); 
        }
    }
///////////////
//2nd Routine//
///////////////
    if (!empty(isset($db_eintrag[pd_nachname] ))) {
                ...
    } else {
        echo "aaaaa";
    }
}
```

Any ideas how i could handle that? i want to build that part:

```
 $sql = "UPDATE personaldaten SET 
            pd_vorname='$db_eintrag[pd_vorname], 
            2nd part, 
            3rd part, etc. 
        ' WHERE pd_id='$db_id'";
```

over an for or foreach Routine to get the part for my mysql query. I tried to put that fixed stuff in 2 Arrays, but i could not get the logic for it how i have to combine that to get just the not empty inputs for it. thx for any repllies and sry for my bad english.

```
$array = array("pd_vorname","pd_nachname", "pd_geburtsjahr");
$array2 = array("$db_eintrag[pd_vorname]","$db_eintrag[pd_nachname]", "$db_eintrag[pd_geburtsjahr]");
```

Comment: why are you still using the `mysql_` library which was deprecated many years ago and removed in PHP7 due to security issues? No new code should be written using this. Your code is almost certainly vulnerable to SQL injection attacks due to the inability to use parameterised queries, and possibly other risks from using a dead codebase. I would strongly suggest migrating to `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible.

Comment: As for your actual question, I don't really know what you are asking. I realise English is not easy for you but please take some time to make it clearer because it's hard to know exactly what your problem is or what you hope to do differently.

Comment: @ADyson : god damn please. i know that new Version, but i began to write all that stuff in the old Version so i could not find the time to Change it. its just lern about the Syntax and so on. thx @ all guys who attent me to Change it, but ist not nessesary for the question. but if you ment ist easy to hack the Server, please let me know how you could do that injection.? if you want i will put an honypot Server on the net and each guys of you get some Attention if you hack that old query function.

Comment: @ADyson: ok sry maybe ist a Little bit hard to understand, but i Need some Input what exactly you could not understand?

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ has an excellent (and humorous) example of some of the risks of your approach, and also some examples of the syntax to use for the new libraries and parameterised queries for PHP and other languages. It's not too hard to learn, and if you do it right from now on it will save you a lot of time having to re-write it later.

Comment: In terms of the question, you say you want to put some SQL into a loop "to get the part for my mysql query". Which part? And what are we looping over? Do you mean to loop the array examples you gave? It looks like _probably_ you shouldn't put the variables in quotes in array2, but without a proper example of what you want to do, and some examples of input and the expected output, it's hard to be sure. Or possibly you want to put all those values into one UPDATE statement? In which case you can do that without any kind of loop

Comment: the way with the arrays isn't wrong. You then would create one function that checks if all the values are set (and maybe verify they are valid [for geburtsdatum zB]). Another function that builds the 'set db_xy=valueForXy' and writes it to an array, which you then can include to your statement after imploding the entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution:

```
$array = array(pd_vorname,"pd_nachname","pd_geburtsjahr","pd_telefonnummer","pd_staatsbuerger","pd_wohnort","pd_fb");
            $zahl = count($array);

            for ($i = 0 ; $i < $zahl ; $i++) {
            $etwas = $db_eintrag[$array[$i]];
            $ar = $array[$i];
                    if (!empty($etwas)) {
                            $sql = "UPDATE personaldaten SET $ar='$etwas' WHERE pd_id='$db_id'";
                            $db_erg = mysql_query( $sql );
                                    if ( ! $db_erg ) { die("Ungültige Abfrage: $sql <hr>" . mysql_error()); }
                    }
            }
            for ($i = 1 ; $i < 12 ; $i++) {
            $etwas = $db_eintrag["wb_wissensbereich_" . $i ];
                    if (!empty($db_eintrag["wb_wissensbereich_" . $i ] )) {
                            $sql = "UPDATE wissensbereiche SET wb_wissensbereich_$i='$etwas' WHERE wb_id_person='$db_id'";
                            $db_erg = mysql_query( $sql );
                                    if ( ! $db_erg ) { die("Ungültige Abfrage: $sql <hr>" . mysql_error()); }
                    }
            }
```